# using Exchange ActiveSync in c#

Tags: c#, exchange-server, activesync

I am trying to use a work email to send confirmation emails programatically in a web app. The mail server is Exchange Server 2007 SP3.

I don't have acces to its configuration and it doesn't seem to implement EWS API.

To give you an example, this is how I the email in order to acces the account on different mobile app clients.

Note that `Domain\Username" input requires only the username, without the domain name.

[image]

This uses Exchange ActiveSync API. Is there a way to use this API to send emails?

All the available resources that I gathered are using EWS API so they aren't much of an use.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons you're finding mostly EWS information is that EAS was a major pain in the [well, you know].

There's very detailed information, even with .NET code, but it'll require some work on your part. With a bit of patience, you'll get there.

Take a look at "[Implementing an Exchange ActiveSync client: the transport mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-interoperability-guidance/hh361570(v%3Dexchg.140))" which has some .NET examples. The command you need to implement is the `SendMail` command, detailed on [page 49 of the specification](https://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-ASCMD/%5BMS-ASCMD%5D.pdf#page49). Exchange 2007 SP3 uses version 12.1 of the protocol.